# How to extract text after a specific sentence with beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to extract the text that comes right after a specific sentence  in my file.

Comment: Show us what you've tried already, and some examples of what your expected input/output is.

Answer (score 1):

Do you specifically require BeautifulSoup? If not use the following:

To split the text right after a specific sentence try this, since I am not sure what you specifically want to extract after the sentence I will assume you mean everything after the sentence,

For example, if I had a file `file.txt:`

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus
>   congue mattis risus, sit amet elementum lorem gravida eu. Cras vitae
>   ante vel erat feugiat scelerisque. Etiam nec urna sed enim blandit
>   blandit non nec odio. Quisque lacinia tempus rhoncus. **Mauris euismod
>   leo ut velit lobortis feugiat.** Phasellus ultrices nunc sit amet tortor
>   pretium eu mollis neque condimentum. Fusce placerat bibendum diam eget
>   euismod. Phasellus ultricies erat nibh, sed volutpat quam. Nunc quis
>   mauris sed purus aliquet aliquam. Integer viverra rutrum arcu ac
>   tempor.

And my sentence was, `Mauris euismod leo ut velit lobortis feugiat.`

You could do this:

```
with open("file.txt") as file: #open a file securily, then automitaclly close it
    seperator = "Mauris euismod leo ut velit lobortis feugiat." #assign pre-opt variable for the sentence
    for line in file:
        text = line.split(seperator,1)[1]
    print text

>>> Phasellus ultrices nunc sit amet tortor pretium eu mollis neque condimentum. Fusce placerat bibendum diam eget euismod. Phasellus ultricies erat nibh, sed volutpat quam. Nunc quis mauris sed purus aliquet aliquam. Integer viverra rutrum arcu ac tempor.
```

Using `BeautifulSoup` you could extract all the text from the file, if you need something more specific let me know.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = """<html><body><div style="DISPLAY: block; TEXT-INDENT: 0pt"><br/></div> <div align="justify" style="DISPLAY: block; MARGIN-LEFT: 0pt; TEXT-INDENT: 0pt; MARGIN-RIGHT: 0pt"><font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial">Our Earnings are Significantly Affected by General Business and Economic Conditions</font></div></body></html>"""

print(soup.get_text())
```

Output:

```
 Our Earnings are Significantly Affected by General Business and Economic Conditions
```

Comment: <div style="DISPLAY: block; TEXT-INDENT: 0pt"><br></div>
    <div style="DISPLAY: block; MARGIN-LEFT: 0pt; TEXT-INDENT: 0pt; MARGIN-RIGHT: 0pt" align="justify"><font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial">Our
Earnings are Significantly Affected by General Business and Economic
Conditions</font></div>

Comment: You should post that in your question.

Comment: sorry. I'm not good at explaining the problem. This file is just a sample. I have thousands of files. And I know that I want the text that comes after <font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial">. I don't know the text itself to put it in code.

Comment: Do they all start after font family, I need more detail

Comment: yes. But there are 2 types of them. one has the  FONT-WEIGHT: bold and one doesn't. So, I want to have it in the code as an separator.